# MSAccess: Err 3146 ODBC Call Fail - Best Strategy for Handling?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an app that requires local users to Sync back to the SQL server periodically (event based, including upon Close/Exit).

My users have occasional internet/VPN issues that throw the expected "3146" error.

Problem:
When ODBC error is thrown, my app LOSES its mind (global variables are lost, etc.) and the app becomes utterly unusable.  There are many subsequent layers of error messages thrown to my users, occasionally requiring a Ctl-Break to interrupt (or task manager).

Question:
I have an err_handler in every module that provides a structured error message.  I am able to trap err_number "3146" in the err_handler module, where I attempt an abrupt "Application.Quit" (to avoid the subsequent err messages).  I still get a couple subsequent err messages before the application fully terminates.

Is there a better approach to more gracefully handling "3146" errors?

Looking for some good ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the error then there should not be a problem. **How** you should be handling the error is to *not* do `Application.Quit`, you should actually do something about the error. A failed connection is not a reason to blow up your app.

Instead, think about caching data locally so that when the connection can be made you can perform your sync again. When you discover your connection failed, stop trying to connect, abort the syncing process, and tell your users "Hey, we couldn't sync now. You might be having VPN issues. Fix those and try to sync again." And all the while your data are still stored in your accdb so that if they go into work the next day and are hardwired into the network they can then sync successfully.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  The "local" data is completely timestamped, so a new re-Sync upon the NEXT login is the current approach and works well.  My issue is interrupting the loop of error messages (Ctl-Break, End is not a good approach).  Once 3146 is encountered, I am not able to reestablish the "connection".

Comment: I did find the err_handler on the OnClose event of the MainForm was the source of err-message after Application.Quit; fixed it.